# Low dimensional structures in a high dimensional space

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let $n \ge 3$ and $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector-valued function of $t \in I = [0,M]$.
Suppose $x_1(t) = [t,\cdots,t]^T = \textbf{1}t$ which is a line, a 1-dimensional manifold. 
Then $$x_1(I) = \{x(t)|t \in I\}$$ can be viewed as a subset in 1-dimension $\mathbb{R}$.
Similarly, if 
$$x_2(t) = [1,1,1,0,\cdots,0]^T\sqrt{1-(t/M)^2} + [0,0,0,1,\cdots,1]^T(t/M),$$ $x_2(I)$ can be viewed as a half circle, as a subset in 2-dimenision $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now let consider 
$$
x_3(t) = [\cos(t-\theta_1), \cos(t-\theta_2), \cdots, \cos(t-\theta_{n})]^T.
$$
In this case, it is unclear that what dimensional object $x_3(I)$ is.

I am wondering if there is a mathematical notion or terminology which describing the dimensionality of $x(I)$ in general (e.g. $x_3(I)$).
But I don't want to (even continuously) deform $x(I)$ to identify the dimensionality. If I allow any deformation on $x(I)$, I believe $x_2(I)$ and $x_3(I)$ become a 1-dimensional "manifold" as they only depend on a single variable $t$.

I can see that $x_1(I)$ is isomorphic to $I$ (as a set) and 
$x_2(I)$ is isomorphic to the half circle $\{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 = 1, 0 \le x, y\}$ (as a set). It seems that these might be related to some isomorphic properties, however, I am not sure.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be very appreciated.

Comment: $x_2$ is still a 1-dimensional object.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this clearly. What I am trying to say is that even the half circle is a line with the curvature, the only way we can realize whether this line is a half circle or not is to put this object into the 2-dimensional space. In this sense, I would like to see this as a 2-dimensional object.

Comment: @Dog_69 For example, $x_2(I)$ is isomorphic to HC (HC = Half Circle) where HC is a subset in "2D", not in 1D.